# iPhone: image in table cell - wrong position & not scaled correctly in iPhone 3.0

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0, uitableview, uiimageview

I have a custom table cell in an iPhone 3.x app to show basketball player data, including a picture.  Here's my code from the table controller:

```
UIImageView *theImage = (UIImageView *) [cell viewWithTag:0];

theImage.image = [manager getSmallImageForPlayer: data.number];         
theImage.frame = CGRectMake(14, 0, 30, 44);
theImage.clipsToBounds = YES;
theImage.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
theImage.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight && UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
theImage.autoresizesSubviews = YES;
```

Here's what it looks like in the iPhone SDK 3.0 simulator:

[3.0 simulator screenshot http://img96.imageshack.us/img96/9550/imageintablecell30.png](http://img96.imageshack.us/img96/9550/imageintablecell30.png)

Here's what it looks like in the iPhone SDK 3.1.3 simulator:

[3.1.3 simulator screenshot http://img185.imageshack.us/img185/9269/imageintablecell313.png](http://img185.imageshack.us/img185/9269/imageintablecell313.png)

So I have two problems:

1. In both versions, the image view starts at position (0,0) in the table cell, even though I set the frame to start at (14,0).
2. In the 3.0 simulator (and 3.0 device), the image is not shrunk down correctly, even though I set the image view content mode to "UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit".  But the same code works fine in the 3.1.3 simulator / device.

Who can help me with either of these two problems?

Comment: How do you add the `UIImageView` to the `UITableViewCell`?

Comment: I don't, it's already in the custom table cell MIB from which I read it with "viewWithTag" and then set its properties.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer on the [Apple forums](https://devforums.apple.com/message/212339): Using "0" as the tag number for the image view screwed things up; just changing it to "5" made both problems (image not scaled, wrong position) go away.

Answer (score 0):

You could try creating your own UIImageView and adding it as a subview to table cell